# Вывод отдельной записи

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5

У меня есть программа в которой выводятся данные в QTableView из таблицы MySql. Как реализовать так, чтобы при нажатии на запись таблицы в списке, подробная информация о конкретной записи выводилась в дополнительном окне.

Нужно чтобы данные записи выводились последовательно, т.е фамилия в 1ом textbox, имя во втором и тд.

Answer (score 0):

В модель таблицы необходимо, как-то, сохранить идентификатор записи в БД. Для получения этого идентификатора из модели создадим роль:

```
int RecordIDRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
```

Конструктор окна, в котором находится таблица с данными.

```
dialog = new InformationDialog();
QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel = tableView->selectionModel()

connect(selectionModel, &QItemSelectionModel::currentRowChanged, 
        [&](const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous) 
        {
            // Получаем ID записи в БД
            int id = current.data(RecordIDRole).toInt();
            if( id >= 0 )
            {
                // Запрос в БД на получение необходимых данных
                // далее
                if ( !dialog->isVisible() )
                    dialog->show();
                dialog->setData(<данные, полученные из таблицы >)
            }
        }
);
```

Сходжий вариант - наследование QTableView и переопределение метода selectionChanged:

```
class MyTable : public QTableView
{
//...
signals:
    void recordSelected(int id);
protected:
    void selectionChanged(const QItemSelection& selected, const QItemSelection& deselected) {
        // если у нас построчный выбор, то берем первый элемент строки
        QModelIndexList& indexes = selected.indexes();
        if( !indexes.isEmpty() )
        {
            int id = indexes[0].data(RecordIDRole);
            // далее мы его эмитируем наружу, а там уже ловим и 
            // обрабатываем как в первом варианте
            emit recordSelected(id);
        }
    }
}
```